# How do I compute the real and imaginary parts of the complex number, $z = \tan (x + ix)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

[Using the Wolfram Alpha website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slRgy.png), the site gave me three alternate forms of $z = \tan (x + ix)$, but my concern is on the third alternate form which has to do with $\sin (x)$, $\cos (x)$, $\sinh (x)$, and $\cosh (x)$. The question here is: How can I obtain that alternate form of $\tan (x + ix)$ mathematically?

Comment: @Lisbeth & Martin R, the link you've both provided shows the alternate form of $tan (z)$ for its real and imaginary parts. What I am after is the real and imaginary part of $tan (x + ix)$; expressing them in terms of $cos (x)$, $sin (x)$, $cosh (x)$ and $sinh (x)$.

Comment: @NzewiErnestKenechukwu: Just set $y = x$ in those expressions ...

Comment: Do you mean $$z=\tan(x+iy)$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, did you click the link associated with my question? The link described as 'Using the Wolfram Alpha Website'